# Dynamically generate tasks in a scripted Jenkin pipeline for parallel execution always with same index

Tags: loops, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I work an a scripted jenkins pipeline to shut down environments within our cloud providers. Since the environments are independent from each other, I want to execute them in parallel.

Here is the code:

```
def environmentsArray=["ZULI-TestCenter", "ZULI-FinanceCenter"]

node("someNode") {

def parEx = [:]

for (def item : environmentsArray) {

    def environment = item

    parEx[environment]= {

   // Identify environments

    environmentLowerCase = environment.split('-')[0].toLowerCase()
    appNameLowerCase = environment.split('-')[1].toLowerCase()

    stage("...) {
          }
    stage("...") {
          }


  } // End of parEx

 } // End of for

parallel parEx

} // End of node
```

Unfortunately the values `environmentLowerCase` and `appNameLowerCase` are not updated per iteration, i.e. they have always the same value:

```
[Pipeline] { (STOPPING DMS tasks: ZULI-TestCenter) // correct
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (STOPPING DMS tasks: ZULI-FinanceCenter) // correct
[Pipeline] echo
zuli, financecenter  // wrong, should be testcenter
[Pipeline] withCredentials
[Pipeline] echo
zuli, financecenter  // correct
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `def` to declare them inside loop.

Comment: You need to make the stages parallel for the environments array iteration. They are currently sequential within the iterator.

Comment: The suggestion from @daggett works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @daggett. I simply hat to add `def`:

```
def environmentsArray=["ZULI-TestCenter", "ZULI-FinanceCenter"]

node("someNode") {

def parEx = [:]

for (def item : environmentsArray) {

    def environment = item

    parEx[environment]= {

   // Identify environments

    def environmentLowerCase = environment.split('-')[0].toLowerCase() // added def
    def appNameLowerCase = environment.split('-')[1].toLowerCase()     // added def

    stage("...) {
          }
    stage("...") {
          }


  } // End of parEx

 } // End of for

parallel parEx

} // End of node
```